# XML tag in Python

Tags: python-requests

I am using Python to call the API and getting response.

below is the response.content

Image
[image]

Here is the code:-

```css
Here is the code:-

response = requests.get(url, params=payload)

if response.status_code == 200:
    print('Success!')
elif response.status_code == 404:
    print('Not Found.')

print(r.content)
tree=ET.fromstring(r.content)
```

How can I get the value of "PYTHON123.Python123" from the returned XML.

Answer (score 1):

Please make use of the following code to extract the string between the tags as shown below,

```
import re

str = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n<string xmlns=\"http://www.PY.com/\">PYTHON123.PYTHON123</string>"
m = re.search('<string.*>(.*?)</string>', str);
print (m.group(1));
```

OUTPUT

```
PYTHON123.PYTHON123
```

While r.content gives you access to the raw bytes of the response payload, you will often want to convert them into a string using a character encoding such as UTF-8. The response will do that for you when you access using **.text method**:

```
response.text
'{"current_user_url":"https://api.github.com/user","current_user_authorizations_html_url":"https://github.com/settings/connections/applications{/client_id}","authorizations_url":"https://api.github.com/authorizations","code_search_url":"https://api.github.com/search/code?q={query}"}'
```

Comment: Thanks. getting error "TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object" . why cannot I use XML to extract the first node?

Comment: use .text method to solve your next problem, as shown in the above example.